# How to use an EJB in a Web Services Java EE

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to use the methods that I have in a *DAO interface*. When i'm calling there in a **Servlet**, I have no problems, for example, if I test

```
@WebServlet("/Index")
public class Index extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //etc
    @EJB
    InterfacesDao dao;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //dao.getUsers(); //works well
        //System.out.println(dao); //will print the dao object correctly
        Boolean logged = dao.login("myLogin","mystrongpassword"); //works
        request.setAttribute("logged",logged);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/login.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    //etc

}
```

But I want to use *ajax* and so pass by a **WebServices**.
I can test

```
@WebService
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String login(@FormParam("login") String login, @FormParam("pwd") String mdp) {
         return "Hello World" + login;
    }
}
```

If I go to `http://[...]/rest/users/login` with an json object which contains a login and a pwd, I get `Hello World theloginientered`
But I need to use **EJB**

```
@WebService
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

    @EJB
    InterfacesDao dao;

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String login(@FormParam("login") String login, @FormParam("pwd") String mdp) {

        //System.out.println(dao); //dao null ?
        //dao.getUsers(); //erros because dao null
        Boolean logged = dao.login(login,pwd); //doesn't work
        //I not arrive till here because NullPointerException error 
        return "Hello World" + login;

    }
}
```

I tried to instance by passing the reference of the dao in my **servlet** to my **Web Service**, but doesn't work
I tried to have just 1 **EJB** in my **WebService**, init in constructor, and get it from my **Servlet** by a *getter*, but again null

I think I forgot a config for the *EJB dependency injection* but in my **Servlet** I do no more less.

Import for the web services

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import com.supinfo.interfaces.InterfacesDao;
import com.supinfo.servlet.Index;
```

Import for the Servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.supinfo.interfaces.InterfacesDao;
```

Interfaces DAO Web side and EJB side

```
package com.supinfo.interfaces;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

import com.supinfo.entity.User;

@Remote
public interface InterfacesDao {

    public boolean login(String login, String mdp);
    public boolean signin(String login, String mdp);
    public List<User> getUsers();

}
```

The Implementation

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import com.supinfo.database.PersistenceManager;
import com.supinfo.entity.User;
import com.supinfo.interfaces.InterfacesDao;

@Stateless
public class InterfaceDaoImpl implements InterfacesDao{

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {

        EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.getEntityManager();
        Query query = (Query) em.createQuery("Select u FROM User u ");
        List<User> persons = query.getResultList();
        return persons;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean login(String login, String mdp) {

        EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.getEntityManager();

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> query = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> person = query.from(User.class);
        query.where(cb.equal(person.get("login"), login)).where(cb.equal(person.get("mdp"), mdp));

        List<User> persons = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        //Boolean isEmpty = persons.isEmpty();
        //return !(isEmpty == null ? false : isEmpty);
        return !persons.isEmpty();

    }
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

The import statements are not included in the sample code, but I assume that you are trying to use JAX-RS and not a WebService. In that case, you should delete the `@WebService` annotation.

Depending on the server (and version) you are using the injection of the `dao` will not instantly work using `@EJB` as annotation. You can however transform the JAX-RS endpoint to a `@Stateless` bean, that should take care of your injection problem.

In short use:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

    @EJB // @Inject is also an option
    InterfacesDao dao;
```

You may also want to use the newer `@Inject` annotation instead of `@EJB`.

Comment: Thank you to respond. But it doesn't works it's the same nullPointeur :  StandardWrapperValve[Jersey Web Application]: Allocate exception for servlet Jersey Web Application
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Could you please update the code with the import statements and include the definition of the InterfacesDao class?

Comment: InterfacesDao is defined as `@Remote`. If you do not need remote access, use a `@Local` interface or a no interface view of InterfaceDaoImpl.